# Jquery- dynamic rows with multiple checkboxes values

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, row

I am creating a shopping cart where the user can dynamically add an item by creating a new row in a table. Each row has 3 checkboxes and I need to perform calculations based on the checkbox values. I have given the rows a class name `data_row` and for the checkbox I am accessing them as

```
$('.data_row').each(function(){

$(this).find('input:checked').each(function(){

------
});
});
```

Here is the html code

```
<tr class="data_row" >
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" style="width:100px; margin-top:25px"></td>

    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Description" style="width:150px;display:inline-block" >

  <span class="checkbox" style=" margin-left:10px; display:inline-block">
    <input type="checkbox" class="item_type" value="General"> General Goods<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="item_type" value="Import">Import<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="item_type" value="BFM">Books,Food, Medical Products
  </span>

      </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control price" placeholder="Price" style="width:100px;margin-top:25px"></td>    
    </tr>
```

I am dynamically inserting the new row by using jquery clone as

```
$(document).on('click','.add',function () {

        $('table tbody>tr.data_row:last').clone(true).find('input').val('').end().find('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked').end().insertAfter('table tbody>tr.data_row:last');
    return false;

  });
```

The issue is the inner loop for finding the checkbox value shows the same data for each row instead of that row's particular checkbox value. I am not able to figure it out. In case you need to see the full code here is the link http://plnkr.co/edit/dUlp7CoBtOOhzmV7LG2A?p=info

Answer (score 0):

Friend it's very simple..
we need to get the particular text box it..

for example,

your cost row text box id is 101, in this case 01 is constant, and 1 is applied to change then

write on on change function some thing like this

```
function getid(obj){
   var i = obj.id.split("01")[0];
   var val = obj.value;
   //now comes to calculation part
   var total += val;
}
```